# Enum React multiple different child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I have following functional component without any props with different children:

```
<Parent>
  <ChildA />
  <ChildB />
  ...
  <ChildG />
</Parent>
```

Is there any way to write all children in *Parent* component not manually, e.g. in loop like:

```
<Parent>
  {childrenArray.map(child => <Child>}
</Parent>
```

If yes, which way is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of JSX elements

```
const childrenArray = [ChildA , ChildB, ChildC];
```

Render like this

```
<Parent>
  {childrenArray.map(Child => <Child />)}
</Parent>
```